# Line Endings in JS Canvas Arc Function bug in Firefox

Tags: html5-canvas

Tiny but mean: I want to draw half a circle with an outline in an JS Canvas in Firefox. Somehow, the line endings of the stroke do not what they should, that would be for my understanding a solid half circle. but the endings are not even in Firefox. Any idea why? (i need it later on for donut charts)

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0,20,0,Math.PI); 
    ctx.lineWidth = 40; 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff00ff"; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"; 
    ctx.lineCap = "butt";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
```

Result Firefox:

[image]

Result Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a Firefox bug. And you did well opening https://bugzil.la/1867774 <sub>(I did open [bug 1868067](https://bugzil.la/1868067) before being pointed to yours)</sub>.

The issue comes from the fact Firefox recently switched their stroke renderer to a GPU accelerated one, where previously they were using Skia's 2D renderer for strokes. However that renderer must be buggy and fails to render arc correctly (in various ways actually).

So to avoid that bug, you can force the browser to use the software renderer, by passing in the `willReadFrequently: true` option at the time of the context's creation. But this also means that nothing will take advantage of the GPU rendering anymore. Depending on what you do on that context it may or may not be a serious hit on perfs. So you may want to measure it thoroughly.

If it does impact your app's performances notably, and if you're going to hit that bug a lot, you can run a test before starting your app, so that only the buggy configs are impacted:

```js
const isBuggy = (() => {
  const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 50;
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  return ctx.getImageData(50, 49, 1, 1).data[3] > 200;
})();
console.log({ isBuggy });

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: isBuggy });
ctx.translate(50, 50);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI); 
ctx.lineWidth = 40; 
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Otherwise, another workaround depending on your setup, could be to pre-render the shape using a deaccelerated canvas (`OffscreenCanvas` seem to be deaccelerated by default, so they may be a good option), and `drawImage` it on your accelerated canvas when needed. This obviously only works if the shape doesn't change over-time.

---

Ps: Another hack-around that seems to do the trick currently: set a line-dash on your context. It seems that they will use the software renderer in that case:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// force software renderer for strokes
ctx.setLineDash([0]);

ctx.translate(50, 50);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI); 
ctx.lineWidth = 40; 
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

However I must admit I'm not sure what will be the side-effects in other engines, i.e. I'm not sure if they'll also use a software renderer of if they'll be unaffected by this hack-around. Also, it's not said that they will always exclude such strokes from the GPU rendering, so I'm not sure it will keep working over-time, but hopefully they'll fix the bug first.