# Is there any way to make canvas arc method behaves same in Firefox & Chrome?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

When you try to draw circle in canvas with lineWidth greater than the radius, it leaves blank space between the filled region and the stroke in chrome. In Firefox & Chromium, the stroke covers the filled region as well. Which behavior is proper? Also, is there any polyfill for chrome to make it work like Firefox?

Code to reproduce the issue:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 200;
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

ctx.arc(250, 250, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
```

**In Chrome:**

[image: In Chrome]

**In Firefox:**

[image: In Firefox]

Comment: Same bug as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77584584/line-endings-in-js-canvas-arc-function-bug-in-firefox/77597113#77597113 with the same workarounds.

Comment: But [Chromium browser](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/) also seems to have same behavior as that of firefox. So, I think it's issue in chrome!

Comment: Oh, I see, it's actually a mix of both o_O. Here is what I see on my Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bywb8.png But even the result when disabling HWA (your first screenshot) actually seems wrong too, that's a Skia bug (Firefox falls back to Skia for CPU rendering). I opened https://issues.skia.org/issues/315864448